# Calculating Ratio in a Ruby Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hobo

Hi, I am doing a data entry system for a local NGO here which conducts surveys about bird in forests. I have four models namely, Bird, Location, Report and Ratio. While Bird & Location are just plain models with only a name field, my report field is as follows.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  hobo_model # Don't put anything above this

  fields do
    Date    :date
    Plumage enum_string(:Breeding, :NonBreeding )
    Weather enum_string(:Cloudy, :Sunny, :Humid)
    Time enum_string(:Dawn, :Morning, :Noon, :Evening, :Dusk, :Night)
    timestamps
  end

  belongs_to :bird
  belongs_to :location

end
```

And in the ratio model I need to calculate a ratio for the following logic.

> Given a scenario that a bird X is found at a location L, the ratio
>   should be equal to number of times bird X is reported at L to the
>   number of total bird reports reported at L. How do I fetch the data
>   from the database into the ratio model?

Answer (score -1):

I answered this question on the Hobo mailing list where you originally posted your question:  http://groups.google.com/group/hobousers/browse_thread/thread/99c267cb96cf3bff